# Angular 4 | Change detection of an array

Tags: angular

How can I manage my array when it is updated or not? My data comes from an API.

I set interval for every 10 seconds so it will get data to a new one.

```
counter = 10;
ngOnInit() {
    this.getVoicepickData();
    // subscribe to API data every 10 seconds
    this.apiTimer = setInterval(() => { 
        this.getVoicepickData();
    }, (this.counter*1000));  
}

getData(){
    // set headers [token]
    let headers = new Headers({
        'token': "My TOKEN",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://api.com/mydata/', options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}

//subscribe to API Data
getVoicepickData() {
    this.showLoader();
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data

        //distribute the api data according to what zone they belong, for ease in manipulatation of data
        for(let mydata of this.data){
            if (mydata.Zone == 1) {
                this.zoneOne.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 2) {
                this.zoneTwo.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 3) {
                this.zoneThree.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 4) {
                this.zoneFour.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 5) {
                this.zoneFive.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 6) {
                this.zoneSix.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 7) {
                this.zoneSeven.push(mydata);
                
            }
            if (mydata.Zone == 8) {
                this.zoneEight.push(mydata);
                
            }
        }
        this.hideLoader();
    },
    () => {
        console.log('Error');
    },
    () => {
        console.log('Complete');
    }
    );
}
```

I want to know how can I manage my api data when there are changes to it, like trigger if my data has new record it will replace my old array to a new one with the latest record on it.

But in my above code, it just keeps pushing the api data everytime my interval occur and get repeated data displayed on my screen.

How can I achieve something like evaluating first my api data if there is a new record or none, and if it has a new record it simply update my array.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement an observable https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/

Comment: yes something like that. i found something EventEmitter but my array came from an API. i just dont know how to evaluate when there is changes on it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do a deep array comparison? If so, I’d strongly recommend finding a different method. Deep array comparisons are extremely buggy.

Comment: @JydonMah You subscribe to the observable, and then implement a callback which will automatically be triggered when the observable is updated. So all you have to do is trigger the update of the variable and this will flow throughout.

Comment: or also what you can do is manually put the change detection strategy to push and when data is pushed you can trigger a change detection by Angular in that method

Comment: @RahulSingh i did try that one but it still dont get it. can you provide once example for my reference? thanks a lot man :)

Comment: @JydonMah updated an answer hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Run change detection manually**

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  (...)
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private change:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  myMethod() {
    this.change.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

More on [`Change Detection`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: thanks rahul, but how can i use this on my loop? sorry to ask this but i still confuse on how changedetector works? how can i apply it on my loop? specially when i push my data this.zoneOne.push(mydata);

Comment: After each push just add a change detection try the same

Comment: it still didnt work. i add this.change.detectChanges(); after i push my data.

Answer (score 0):

instead of push use this code:

```
this.zoneOne = [...this.zoneOne, mydata]
this.zoneTwo = [...this.zoneTwo, mydata]
```